# Download 12.10 gives 12.04.01 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, downloads

I'm a Newbie just experimenting.  When I download 12.10 by clicking on the **GET Ubuntu 12.10** button I actually get 12.04.1 LTS.

Installed it works fine on a ancient Dell Inspirion 8000 that I had retired ... but I would have liked to get the latest and greatest just to poke around and see what's it about.

Comment: Please provide the link you used to download this 12.10 which turned out to be 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Apart from your initial question, please don't try the latest and greatest on such an old device. It's simply not fit for it. Try the `old-computer` tag here on the site to search for similar questions/tips and ask perhaps on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for a broader-than-Ubuntu advice.

Comment: Have you previously downloaded 12.04.1?  If so, it's possible that you're just accessing the wrong location.  Not trying to shift blame or anything, but personally, I've found that user error has been the source of many of my problems in the past - so much so, that I double-check every assumption when I have a problem before assuming a bug.  The link at ubuntu.com seems to be OK, though.

Comment: I just tried the download you describe and it does lead to a 12.10 version. Can you provide your link? Otherwise this question should be closed.

Comment: @gertvdijk - well, the OP did say that it worked fine on his computer. However, if you want to stay with Ubuntu but have an old machine, I normally recommend [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate, I often skip the download page and use one of the mirrors. They can be found here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads